# Square Roots on Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, manifolds

Let $G_n = GL_n(\mathbb{R})^+$ be the open subset of $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of nxn invertible matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ with positive determinant.

1. Show that there is some $r>0$ for which there is a continuously differentiable function $g:B(I_n,r)$ such that $g(A)^2=A$.
2. Does such a function exist on all of $G_n$?

---

My attempt:

I can show 1 directly from the implicit function theorem as follows:

If we let $h:G_n \times G_n \rightarrow \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$, $h(A,B) = B^2-A$, then $h(I_n, I_n) = 0$.

If $f(B) = B^2$, we can show from direct computation that $Df_B(H) = BH + HB$, so at $I_n$, $Df_{I_n}(H) = 2H$.

Hence the derivative of $h$ at $(I_n,I_n)$ is given by $(X|Y) = (-I_{n\times n} | 2I_{n\times n})$ by identifying elements of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the standard basis on $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Then since $Y$ is invertible, the implicit function theorem guarantees 1.

However, I'm not sure how to approach the second part of the question.

Comment: What is $B(I_n,r)$?

Comment: It's the ball centered at $I_n$ of radius $r$. Since $G_n$ has finite dimension, every norm on it is topologically equivalent, so it doesn't really matter which norm is used here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could improve your post by giving a short proof why 1. is correct (so the readers will see how this can help with 2., i.e., whether or not you have used compactness, or why we can't simply extend it to $G_n$).

Comment: Hint: think about $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the link, could you elaborate a little more?